# 403 error only in chrome, works fine in FF and IE

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat7, http-status-code-403

I have an application, when I clicked login button, I got an 403 error, and it only happens in Chrome, works fine in all of the other browsers.

Here is the log I found from the tomcat log file (localhost_access_log.2015-03-11.txt):

`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Mar/2015:20:27:42 -0700] "POST /app/login/do_login HTTP/1.1" 403 -
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [11/Mar/2015:20:28:25 -0700] "POST /app/login/do_login HTTP/1.1" 403 -`

PS: Our backend is written in java, we are using spring security for authentication, tomcat 7.0.57 is the version we are using.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days' research, I found that that's because I have CorsFilter configured in my tomcat, and Chrome will add an "origin" element in the form submit request if the request type is "POST" by default, even the request has the same host.

Comment: what the solution?

Comment: This bug got fixed in 8.0.x for 8.0.21 onwards and 7.0.x for 7.0.60 onwards. What is the tomcat version you are using?

Comment: If the CorsFilter org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter is defined as a <filter> in web.xml, it can be commented out (then restart Tomcat) to prevent the 403.